# Persistent Spikes in Binary Cross Entropy Loss

Tags: machine-learning, python, optimization, loss-functions

I'm working on a binary classification task and there is something with the batch loss that is not working well, but I can't figure out what is it. Here is the loss per epoch and loss per batch:

[image]

The loss is clearly decreasing every epoch, but if you look at the loss per batch, it moves every epoch in a huge range. Here is some of my code:

```
class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim):
        super(DNN, self).__init__()
        
        self.ln1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, 32)
        self.ln2 = nn.Linear(32, 64)
        self.ln3 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.norm = nn.BatchNorm1d(64)
        self.ln6 = nn.Linear(64, 64)
        self.ln7 = nn.Linear(64, 32)
        self.ln8 = nn.Linear(32, 1)
        self.sigmoid = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x):        
        out = self.ln1(x)
        out = self.ln2(out)
        out = self.ln3(out)
        out = self.norm(out)
        out = self.ln6(out)
        out = self.ln7(out)
        out = self.ln8(out)
        out = self.sigmoid(out)
        return out.squeeze()

model = Model(32)
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
loss_function = nn.BCELoss()
```

I'm using a batch size of 64, the batch loss is calculated and stored for each batch, and at the end of each epoch I store the current batch loss as epoch loss, (I'm not sure if this is the proper way of doing this). Here is the training code:

```
EPOCHS = 100
BATCH_SIZE = 64

training_batch_loss = []
epoch_training_loss = []
for ii in range(EPOCHS):
        for i in range(1, X_train.size()[0]//BATCH_SIZE+1):
            x_train = X_train[(i-1)*BATCH_SIZE:i*BATCH_SIZE]
            labels = y_train[(i-1)*BATCH_SIZE:i*BATCH_SIZE]

            optimizer.zero_grad()

            y_pred = model(x_train)

            single_loss = criterion(y_pred, labels.detach())
            
            
            training_batch_loss.append(single_loss.item()) 

            single_loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
            print(f"\rBatch {i}/{X_train.size()[0]//BATCH_SIZE+1} Trained: {i*BATCH_SIZE}/{X_train.size()[0]} Loss: {single_loss.item():10.8f} Step: {lr_scheduler.get_last_lr()[0]}", end="")

        epoch_training_loss.append(single_loss.item())
```

I know that having some spikes in the loss is normal specially when you have a small batch size, but I don't understand why my batch loss moves that much on each epoch, even when the epoch loss is decreasing, any idea about what is happening?

Comment: I notice that your network has a dropout layer. Does this happen even if you don’t use dropout? Or is there a copy-paste error, and you've declared a dropout layer but never used it?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, you're right, I declared the dropout layer but never use it. I have already edited the post. I've also tried removing the batch norm layer, but I get the same spikes in the loss, maybe I should check the optimizer.

Comment: Reducing the learning rate might help reduce this effect, but what I think is happening is that some batches have harder examples, or simply the vagaries of random sampling mean that some batches will have much higher loss values than others. The loss is decreasing from epoch to epoch, so you're in good shape.

Comment: I've tried reducing the lr, with a lr of `1e-3` I get the best results, even with `1e-2` works well, when I reduce the lr below `1e-3` the loss just get stuck between `0.7-0.6` and doesn't learn anything at all.

Comment: I think the data is pretty complex, I will try improving it, I have tried adding more complexity and depth to the neural network but it doesn't seem to be the issue, thanks for your help @Sycorax!

Comment: for what it’s worth, this jagged behavior in each batch doesn't seem to stop the model from learning (the loss decreases during most epochs), so I'm not sure that *more* complexity is really a good solution (unless you feel that the model is under-fitting or something, which seems like a separate issue).